# Java: Using Generics for String Parsing to Improve DRYness

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I need to parse space delimited lists of numbers where some lists contain integers and some lists contain doubles. What would be a good way to generalize the following functions to reduce repetition? I was thinking this might be a good use case for Generics?

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> stringToIntList(String str)
{
    String[] strs = str.split("\\s");
    ArrayList<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();
​
​
    for (String val : strs)
    {
        output.add(Integer.parseInt(val));
    }
​
    return output;
}
​
public static ArrayList<Double> stringToDoubleList(String str)
{
    String[] strs = str.split("\\s");
    ArrayList<Double> output = new ArrayList<Double>();
​
​
    for (String val : strs)
    {
        output.add(Double.parseDouble(val));
    }
​
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with generics if you have some sort of function (e.g. [`java.util.function.Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) or [`com.google.common.base.Function`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html)) which takes a `String` and returns the desired type.

```
static <T> ArrayList<T> stringToList(
    String str, Function<? super String, ? extends T> fn) {
  String[] strs = str.split("\\s");
  ArrayList<T> output = new ArrayList<>();
  for (String val : strs)
  {
      output.add(fn.apply(val));
  }
  return output;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

With Java 8, it can be quite concise:

```
static <T> List<T> convertToList(
        String string, Function<String, T> function) {
    return Pattern.compile("\\s").splitAsStream(string)
            .map(function).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "3 4";
    System.out.println(convertToList(s,Double::parseDouble)); // [3.0, 4.0]
    System.out.println(convertToList(s,Integer::parseInt)); // [3, 4]
}
```

You can make the Pattern also a constant when it does not change.

Comment: When I try this, I get an error saying that the function is returning a `List<java.lang.Object>` rather than a `List<T>`. Do I need a cast there or something?

Comment: @evan058 how do you call it? You need to pass a function which returns T, but if T is Object you get List<Object>

Comment: I am using IntelliJ and the IDE is throwing that error. I have just defined the function and it says: Incompatible Types: Required: `List<T>`; Found `List<java.lang.Object>`

Comment: Ah, you need to do `Collectors.<T>toList()` rather than `Collectors.toList()`

Comment: Even still when I try to run `ArrayList<Double> dubTimes = convertToList(times, Double::parseDouble)` I get an error "Bad return type in method reference, cannot convert double to T" Andy Turner's answer works with this kind of method call

Comment: @evan058 It works for me. I have added an example how I call it. Maybe you use an old version of IntelliJ which does not provide complete support for Java 8.